# In a Rails app running on multiple servers, how can I make sure a rake task runs only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a Rails app running on 2 servers in production.

I have a rake task that runs some import and then sends out an email to the users. I receive 2 emails now since there are 2 servers.

To avoid this, I tried creating a table `my_import_run`.

1. My import would check if a record with current date exists in the table, only if NOT the import would be run and email would be sent.
2. After sending email, all records in the table would be deleted and a record with only current date would be added

The above algorithm is implemented as shown here:

```rb
def self.import(search_date = Date.current)
  if 0 == MyImportRun.count || !MyImportRun.where(:last_run => Date.today).any?
    # the code to run import job and send email goes here
    #
    #
    #
    #
    MyImportRun.delete_all
    MyImportRun.new(:last_run => Date.today)
    MyImportRun.save    
  end
```

But even after implementing the above code, I still receive 2 emails - I have no idea why. I was wondering maybe both the imports run at the exact same time and hence they both would find no records with current date and run import, send email and delete all records and add records with current date.

Is there a clean way of avoiding this from happening? The rake tasks would be automatically imported into cron job in Linux from what I understand; so I cannot delete the rake file from just one server.

Am sure there must be a clean way to avoid this duplication.

Comment: What way do you use for running the task on the servers? Whenever gem?

Comment: That's correct. I use whenever gem.

Comment: If you're willing to change "cron" platform, you could use [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask). It'll only run the task once.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Whenever` and `Capistrano` that can be done with `roles`:
in a deploy file, you can set up a list of the roles:

```ruby
server 'first-server', user: 'deployer', roles: %w{app db web sidekiq job}, primary: true
server 'second-server', user: 'deployer', roles: %w{app db web sidekiq job2}
```

and in the `schedule.rb`:

```ruby
every 1.day, at: '5:00am', roles: [:job] do # this task will be run only on the first server
  rake "-s sitemap:refresh:no_ping"
end
every 1.day, at: '5:00am', roles: [:job2] do # this only on second
  rake "another_rake_task"
end
```

More details you can find [this](https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-roles)

Comment: thanks much for your reply. I saw the link you had shared - I could not find any info on `primary: true` in that though. Could you please throw some light on what exactly does `primary: true` do?

Comment: Is `primary: true` the key to solving my issue?

Comment: I am not sure but seems like `primary` server using for run migration

Comment: Thanks much for your help - I found this link gave the info I needed (the example section) - https://makandracards.com/makandra/48857-decide-whether-cronjobs-should-run-on-one-or-all-servers

Comment: I'll try this suggestion in my production evnvironment and mark your reply as the correct answer in a couple of days. Thanks much again!